# UseRef to select the parent component of the actual one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ref, use-ref

I'm using useRef to select a component and print it.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';

const Details = ({ view }) => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current
  });

  return (
    <div className="order-details-section" ref={componentRef}>
      <div className="return-an-issue-header">
        <div className="return-an-issue-title"></div>
        {view && (
          <div className="print-items-container">
            <p onClick={handlePrint}>click to print</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

It works fine but only for the current component which is a part from the whole page. I would like to print the parent component, or to pass it by the className.

Is it possible to do something like that? To get the parent component in useRef or to select it by class?

Comment: Why don't you use the hook in parent component, if you have to print the parent component?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri because the button for print must be situated inside the child component. Styling issues

Comment: Added an answer on the approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `useReactToPrint` to the parent and pass on the handlePrint function as props to the child component if you want to access a ref of the parent and print it

```
const Details = ({ view, handlePrint}) => {

  return (
    <div className="order-details-section">
      <div className="return-an-issue-header">
        <div className="return-an-issue-title"></div>
        {view && (
          <div className="print-items-container">
            <p onClick={handlePrint}>click to print</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

---

```
const Parent = () => {

  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
      content: () => componentRef.current
  });
  return (
      <div ref ={componentRef}> 
         <div>Some other content</div>
         <Details view={...} handlePrint={handlePrint}/>
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: it says that `handlePrint` in Child is not defined. Shouldn't it be sent as props?

Comment: @JeanPierre, yes it should be sent as props, missed it while editing

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the ref to the child component like how you normally pass props to child component.

**Do note:** Ref does not trigger rerendering, so when the input value changes, you need to click the button to get the new value.

This is just a code example to demostrate passing of ref to child component.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-euclid-8eys3?file=/src/App.js:0-587)

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <ChildComponent parentRef={inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildComponent = ({ parentRef }) => {
  console.log("parentRef", parentRef);

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const getValue = () => {
    setValue(parentRef.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Child Component</h1>
      {value}
      <button onClick={getValue}>Get Value</button>
    </>
  );
};
```